# Adding comma separator for every nth character

Tags: apex

I want to separate every nth of character by comma separator. For Example, I have string contains like '**Cameraman is not available today**'. I need to split this string by comma separator in every 5th character. So output must be like '**Camer,aman ,is no,t ava,ilabl,e tod,ay**'.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions can greatly simplify this problem. You can reinsert matched groups using `$g`, where `g` is the group number. In this case, it would be `0` since you just want to replace the whole group. So just replace every five characters with the same five characters followed by a comma. One-liner:

```
system.debug('Cameraman is not available today'.replaceAll('.{5}', '$0,'));
// Camer,aman ,is no,t ava,ilabl,e tod,ay
```

---

If that's too hard to follow, you might find `Pattern`/`Matcher` useful here. You can just have a matcher gobble up an arbitrary number of characters at a time using `.{1,N}`. From there, you just need to split the chunks out into a collection and then join it back together with whatever delimiter you wish.

```
String inject(String input, String delimiter, Integer charactersBetween)
{
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile('.{1,' + charactersBetween + '}').matcher(input);
    List<String> chunks = new List<String>();
    while (m.find()) chunks.add(m.group());
    return String.join(chunks, delimiter);
}

system.debug(inject(
    'Cameraman is not available today', ',', 5
)); // yields 'Camer,aman ,is no,t ava,ilabl,e tod,ay'
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be like this:

```
String str = 'Cameraman is not available today';
String newStr='';
List<String> lstStr = new List<String>();
Integer j = 0;
Integer lengthToTrim = 5;

while (j<str.length())
{
   newStr = str.mid(j,lengthToTrim);
   lstStr.add(newStr);
   j = j + lengthToTrim;
} 

String.join(lstStr, ',');
System.debug('lstStr=' + lstStr);
```

> DEBUG|lstStr=(Camer, aman , is no, t ava, ilabl, e tod, ay)

For more information, refer [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)